# napari: RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QtLayerListModel has been deleted

Tags: python, runtime-error, python-napari

I am trying to open an image using napari as an image viewer for python. The image is of format tiff and for some reason I keep getting the same error: **RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QtLayerListModel has been deleted**.

Here is my code, any idea of what I can do to solve it?:

```
%gui qt5
from skimage import data
import napari
from tifffile import imread, imwrite

newImg = imread('labels_nucleus.tif')

viewer.add_image(newImg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this mistake occurs but simply converting images to NumPy arrays after reading worked for me.

Comment: Hello! Try to describe better your solution, provide a code snippet could be nice.